# Open VF page when clicked on lookup icon with conditional records

Tags: set, salesforce, lookup, apex

i am trying to get this running with some modifications.
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/

I have to get those accounts of which my contact is having contact role and account which it belongs to.

I have written soql query and having different accounts from two ojbects.
I saved the list as set to avoid duplicates.

my second vf page shows account names but when i select account name,in my first vf page i get this error.

Error:  value '{!Cas.AccountId}' is not a valid id field
Yes because i am adding value to set as 
set.add(variable.name);
this displays account name..if i add ids,it dislays ids on vf page which user cant understand.

i am struck here and cant get goin!!!
Please guide me!!!!!!

Thanks in advance!!!!!
My second vf page and class

```
    <apex:page controller="Customaccountlookupcontroller" tabStyle="Account" showHeader="false" title="Search" id="pg" sidebar="false">
     <apex:form >
         <apex:outputPanel id="page" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" id="tabbedPanel">

      <!-- SEARCH TAB -->
      <apex:tab label="Search" name="tab1" id="tabOne">

        <apex:actionRegion >  
          <apex:outputPanel id="top" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">
            <apex:outputLabel value="Search" style="font-weight:Bold;padding-right:10px;" for="txtSearch"/>
            <apex:inputText id="txtSearch" value="{!searchString}" />
              <span style="padding-left:5px"><apex:commandButton id="btnGo" value="Go" action="{!Search}" rerender="searchResults"></apex:commandButton></span>
          </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:outputPanel id="pnlSearchResults" style="margin:10px;height:350px;overflow-Y:auto;" layout="block">
            <apex:pageBlock id="searchResults">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!allaccts}" var="a"> 
            <apex:column >           
            <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:outputPanel >Account Name</apex:outputPanel>                
            </apex:facet> 
              <apex:outputLink value="javascript:top.window.opener.lookupPick2('{!FormTag}','{!TextBox}_lkid','{!TextBox}','{!a}','{!a})', false)" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(a))}">{!a}</apex:outputLink>   
            </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
          </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:actionRegion>

      </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
  </apex:outputPanel>          
     </apex:form>      
</apex:page>
```

apex class:

```
Public with sharing class Customaccountlookupcontroller{

    Public set<string> allaccts{get;set;}
    public string searchString{get;set;}
    Public list<account> results{get;set;}
    Public string selectedkey{get;set;}

    public Customaccountlookupcontroller() {

    allaccts =  new set<string>();

  //Contact objcontact =[select accountid,(select AccountId,Account.name from AccountContactRoles) from Contact where id=:userList[0].contactId];
    Contact objContact =[select AccountId,Account.name,(select AccountId,account.name from AccountContactRoles) from Contact where Id='00317000006VtoR'];

    for(AccountContactRole obj: objContact.AccountContactRoles)
    {    
    allaccts.add(obj.account.name);
    allaccts.add(objContact.account.name);
    }
    System.debug('*******objcontact:'+allaccts);    
    }

    public PageReference search() {

    return null;
     }

   }
    public string getFormTag() {
    return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('frm');
    }

    public string getTextBox() {
    return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('txt');
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't getting an `Account` record back from your queries (and that is the major difference between your code and jeff's code), you'll need to create an account wrapper object. This object would be an internal class of your controller.

The wrapper could look like this:

```
public class AccountWrapper {
public String name {get; set;}
public Id accountId {get; set;}

    public AccountWrapper(String name, String accountId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }
}
```

You would then create AccountWrapper objects to use in your list on the VF page

```
for(AccountContactRole obj: objContact.AccountContactRoles) {   
    allaccts.add(new AccountWrapper( obj.account.name, obj.AccountId ));
    allaccts.add(new AccountWrapper( objContact.account.name, objContact.AccountId ));
}
```

Of course, you'd need to redefine your list to be used on the VF page:

```
Public set<Customaccountlookupcontroller.AccountWrapper> allaccts{get;set;}
```

Hopefully this will get you closer to your goal. What I would also do is simplify this example to make sure that this wrapper class is working properly for you first - then build it back up.

Don't forget to modify your VF page to accommodate the wrapper class member variable names.

**UPDATE:**  If the list has duplicates, you can track them by storing the ids in a set and checking this set before adding to your list like so:

```
Set<Id> idSet = new Set<Id>();

for(AccountContactRole obj: objContact.AccountContactRoles) {   
    //prevent duplicates. Since we are using two different sObjects, we can't just add to a set to remove duplicates.
    //so we add the account ids to a set (and check this set before adding to our list)
    if (!idSet.contains(obj.AccountId)){
        allaccts.add(new AccountWrapper( obj.account.name, obj.AccountId ));
        idSet.add(obj.AccountId);
    }
    if (!idSet.contains(objContact.AccountId)){
        allaccts.add(new AccountWrapper( objContact.account.name, objContact.AccountId ));
        idSet.add(objContact.AccountId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok CaspNz...but to my surprise ,it is showing duplicates accounts on my VF page.I am using set. Also when i use {!a.name }or anything other than {!a} it just gives me error.Unknown property 'setValue.name' or accountid.Can you please guide me with VF page edits too..just to make sure i am on right path!! Thank you!

Comment: This is what i have on my Vf page now:                              AccountWrapper:[accountId=0011700000jhk4nYAAU, name=test account1]            I need help in fixing this and also the duplicates..Even though i am using set,still i have duplicate accounts.accounts. Of coarse not all accounts are duplicated but only account which i am getting from here(from this lline of code;        allaccts.add(new AccountWrapper( objContact.account.name, objContact.AccountId ));
 is showing duplicate account.Please guide me!!!Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `setValue` - can you post the relevant updated apex code in your question?

Comment: A set will not allow duplicate sObjects, but it's got no way of knowing that the AccountWrapper objects are duplicates. You might have to scan for duplicate ids before adding to your wrapper class.

Comment: Added a way to check for dupes before adding to the list

Comment: No worries! An upvote would be nice too... it took a while :)

Comment: i wish i could upvote.But upvote needs 15 reputation.thank you